# how to create static QLabel in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, static, qlabel

Is it possible to create some `static` `QLabel`s in one class, and other classes can access its `QLabel`s variable and apply changes to the `QLabel`s without creating its object? 
I found some answers online like if you want to access one class variables without creating its object in another class, you have to make its data `static`.
So basically what I am trying to do here is accessing and changing one class variables, for me it is `QLabel`s, in another class without creating its object.
I know how to create `static` variables, but when comes to declare a `staic QLabel`, I found it difficult to achieve it.

Comment: Why not just using [signal/slot](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) to change the object from another object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may just make the label *accessible*, i.e. expose it as a public member. Say you have a `Form` class, and a `label` `QLabel` in its `ui`. Add this method to the class:

```
public:
    QLabel * label();
```

the implementation is just:

```
QLabel *Form::label()
{
    return ui->label;
}
```

If all you need to expose is the label text property, just add these two accessors methods:

```
public:
    QString labelText();
    void setLabelText(QString & text);
```

in implementation file:

```
QString Form::labelText()
{
    return ui->label->text();
}

void Form::setLabelText(QString &text)
{
    ui->label->setText(text);
}
```

These last strategy fits encapsulation better.

About having it static: what if you have more than one instance of the `Form` class? Which label is supposed to be pointed to by the static member? If you are 100% sure you will have only one instance of the widget, you can add a static public `QLabel *` member:

```
public:
    static QLabel * label;
```

in implementation file, on top:

```
QLabel *Form::label = 0;
```

in `Form` constructor:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
if(label == 0)
{
    label = ui->label;
}
```

Again, this makes sense if you have one `Form` instance only. Otherwise, the static pointer will point forever to the label of the widget which was created first (and, dangerously, to nothing when that instance gets destroyed).